# Отступы вложенных элементов влияют на размер родителя

Tags: css, css3

Есть блок с элементами `div` в виде плитки, сам блок - `display: flex`, вложенные элементы имеют некоторый отступ снизу - `margin-bottom: 2rem`. В результате этого, высота родительского блока вычисляется с учетом `margin`'ов нижних вложенных элементов. Есть возможность этого избежать кроме как задавать нижним элементам по `nth-child` нулевой отступ?

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.child {
  width: 31.5%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0cwa1e4n/

Comment: код выложитефыв

Comment: @meine, поправил вопрос.

Comment: Если не нужна рамка вокруг блока, можно сделать вложенным блокам отступ сверху, а родительскому элементу отрицательный отступ сверху.
Если нужна рамка, то либо как вы уже предложили добавлять/убирать отступы элементам по `nth-child`, либо нарисовать рамку псевдоэлементом, задав ему высоту меньшую на размер отступа.

Comment: @kost1k, да, видимо, других вариантов нет. Спасибо, сделал как раз через отрицательный отступ.